# Setting default values via constructor does not work (Lightning Component)

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, controller

I want to write a lightning component. The lightning component should show some informations about uploaded documents. Firstly I created the following class:

```
public class DocInformations {
    @AuraEnabled
    public integer numberOfSelectedDocs { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public integer numberOfUploadedDocs { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public boolean hasSelectedDocs { get; set; }

    public DocumentInformations() {
        this.numberOfSelectedDocs = 0;
        this.numberOfUploadedDocs = 0;
        this.hasSelectedDocs = false;
    }
}
```

Secondly I created an object and fill some values. And finally I want to return the object as a json string.

```
DocInformations docInfos = new DocInformations();
docInfos.numberOfSelectedDocs = 1;
docInfos.hasSelectedDocs = true;
return JSON.serialize(docInfos);
```

But the field numberOfUploadedDocs is missing in the response json string:

```
{ "numberOfSelectedDocs": 1, "hasSelectedDocs": true }
```

I'am unsing a constructor to fill all fields with default values. I need the dafault values in the response and I don't want to write them every time again. Could someone tell me what's wrong with the constructor? Thanks!

Comment: By the way: How it even saved/compiled? You should recieve error AFAIK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is:

You're not using default constructor because your default constructor name doesn't match class name.

Its  `DocInformations` and `DocumentInformations`

Constructor name should also be named `DocInformations`

You're setting properties via getters and setters. That's why only two values are set.

```
public class DocInformations {
@AuraEnabled
public integer numberOfSelectedDocs { get; set; }
@AuraEnabled
public integer numberOfUploadedDocs { get; set; }
@AuraEnabled
public boolean hasSelectedDocs { get; set; }

public DocInformations() {
    this.numberOfSelectedDocs = 0;
    this.numberOfUploadedDocs = 0;
    this.hasSelectedDocs = false;
}
}

DocInformations docInfos = new DocInformations();
docInfos.numberOfSelectedDocs = 1;
docInfos.hasSelectedDocs = true;
system.debug(JSON.serialize(docInfos));

USER_DEBUG [4]|DEBUG|{"numberOfUploadedDocs":0,"numberOfSelectedDocs":1,"hasSelectedDocs":true}
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right.. I changed the code a lot to test why the constructor never was set and I forgot to change the constructor methodname. Thanks!

Comment: @user1974566 I know this is an old question, but what did you mean by: "You're setting properties via getters and setters. That's why only two values are set.". All 3 are set up in the same way - so why would only 2 be set?

Comment: docInfos.numberOfSelectedDocs = 1;
docInfos.hasSelectedDocs = true

That's 2 :) Aura automatically get rid of property which is not set (is null by default)